# Prove: if $P(C)=P(A) \cup P(B)$ then $A=C$ or $B=C$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Given 3 sets: $A, B, C$, suppose that: $$P(C) =P(A)\cup P(B)$$ as $P(A), P(B), P(C)$ are the power sets of $A, B$ and $C$.

**Prove**: $A=C$ or $B=C$

**My attempt:**

Let $|A| = n, |B| = m$.

I do not suppose that this sets are finite, neither do I assume that $n, m >0$.

I divided into cases:

1. WLOG Let $ B = \emptyset \Longrightarrow P(A)\cup P(B) = P(A)$, then $P(A) = P(C) \Longrightarrow A =C$, and we're done.
2. Let $A, B \neq \emptyset \land (A \cap B) =\emptyset$ , then:$$P(A)\cup P(B) = 2^{n} + 2^{m} -1$$  which means
   $$|P(A) \cup P(B)| = |P(C)| = 2^{n} +2^{m} -1 $$

As $n, m \neq 0$, there exist no $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|P(C)| = 2^N$, and this a contradiction to cantor theorem for power sets, therefore $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$, unless $A$ or $B  = \emptyset$.

now I understand why for $A \lor B \neq \emptyset$, only if $A\subseteq B$ or $B\subseteq A$, and $C = A$ or $C = B$, then it's possible that $P(A)\cup P(B) =P(C)$, but I can't find a way to prove that argument.

Comment: We have $ C \in P(C)$, hence $C \subseteq A$ or $C \subseteq B$. The same way one gets $A \subseteq C$ and $B\subseteq C$.

Comment: If you're not assuming that the sets are finite, then reasoning from the _sizes_ of the sets is doomed to fail. Even if you were to deduce, say, that $A\subseteq C$ and $|A|=|C|$ you would not be able to conclude that $A=C$. Also the "WLOG" appears to be completely misplaced here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my final answer, based on @John comment:

By a definition, $A\in P(A),B\in P(B)$, Therefore $A, B \in P(A)\cup P(B)$.

as $P(A)\cup P(B)=P(C),\ A,B\in P(C)\Longrightarrow A,B\subseteq C$.

symmetrically, $C\in P(A)\cup P(B)$, which means $C\subseteq A$ or $C\subseteq B$, Hence $A=C$ or $B=C$.

Comment: Yes that's right!

Answer (score 0):

Please do not take this answer  into account. For the alledged theorem (2) invoked below   is NOT correct in general.

See: [If set $X$ is not equal to set $Y$, then $X\cup Z$ is not equal to $Y\cup Z$ ( for all $Z$). Is this correct?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3272602/if-set-x-is-not-equal-to-set-y-then-x-cup-z-is-not-equal-to-y-cup-z-f)

---

Below a proof attemp in natural deduction style.

The attempt is indirect ( and uses contraposition at line (31) ).

It takes into account two possibilities : A is equal to B or A is not equal to B.

It makes use of three  alledged theorems :

(1) X is included in Y iff  X Union Y = Y

(2) if X is not equal to Y, then X Union Z is not equal to Y Union Z ( for all Z)

(3) X = Y iff P(X) = P(Y)

[image]