# If set $X$ is not equal to set $Y$, then $X\cup Z$ is not equal to $Y\cup Z$ ( for all $Z$). Is this correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In an attempt at proving a [proposition regarding power sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3270680/prove-if-pc-pa-cup-pb-then-a-c-or-b-c/3272591#3272591) I make use of the alleged theorem , that seems to me intuitively correct :

> If  set $X$ is not equal to set $Y$, then  $X\cup Z$ is not equal to $Y\cup Z$ ( for all $Z$).

Is this proposition correct?

In case it is, does it have a name?

Answer (score 5):

Certainly false. Take any example where $X \neq Y$ and take $Z=X \cup Y$.

Answer (score 1):

False. Take $X = \{1\}$, $Y = \{1,2\}$, $Z = \{2,3\}$.